# Bootstrap breaks my gif animation after opening in browser. Gif stops abruptly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I need to open a pop-up tutorial with four steps. Each step has a gif showing what to do, dots to show progress, text to explaining the step. The code works perfectly fine when used as a slideshow on a webpage. I put the code into a bootstrap modal to get the popup thing work. Now, popup does work but the gif is behaving weirdly. I observed it is the bootstrap CSS causing it but don't know how to fix it. Any guidance would be really appreciated.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName("mytext");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
      text[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  text[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* * {box-sizing: border-box} */
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none; vertical-align: middle;}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
.mytext {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #33A849;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".cd-example-modal-lg">More In</button>
<div class="modal fade modal-fade cd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="slideshow-container" style="width:50%">
            <div class="mySlides fade">
          <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/Y3AbrXYYwtHHChK00a/giphy.gif" style="height:250px">
                </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
          <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/SXaQdkJxPHGGwXNEeY/giphy.gif" style="height:250px">
                </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
          <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/WmiuaNK5ARbSIld4Y0/giphy.gif" style="height:250px">
                </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
          <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/SVaJz9DQfv0xLXPSHm/giphy.gif" style="height:250px">
                </div>
            <div style="text-align:center">
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mytext">
                    <p>Step 1: Analyse Students’ Data</p>
                    <p>Select ‘Assessed Level’ to view data based on your students’ current level.</p>
                    <p>To see where your students sit in relation to their grade, select ‘Grade’.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mytext">
                    <p>Step 2: Select Individual Cells for Goal Sheets</p>
                    <p>Select the skills you want your students to develop by clicking on the individual cells.  Skills highlighted in light or dark orange indicate students are working below their assessed level for these skills.  These are ‘growth opportunities’, so you may want to generate goals sheets for these particular skills. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="mytext">
                    <p>Step 3: Generate all Goal Sheets</p>
                    <p>To generate all the student goal sheets as one PDF document, click on ‘Generate all Goal Sheets'. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="mytext">
          <p>Step 4: (Optional) Generate Individual Goal Sheets</p>
                <p>To generate individual student goal sheets, click on the download button next to the student’s name. This will enable you to print or email goal sheets for individual students. </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: any problem with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `fade` class from your `modal`

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName("mytext");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
      text[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  text[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* * {box-sizing: border-box} */
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none; vertical-align: middle;}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
.mytext {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #33A849;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".cd-example-modal-lg">More In</button>
<div class="modal fade modal-fade cd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="slideshow-container" style="width:50%">
            <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/Y3AbrXYYwtHHChK00a/giphy.gif" style="height:250px">
                </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/SXaQdkJxPHGGwXNEeY/giphy.gif" style="height:250px">
                </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/WmiuaNK5ARbSIld4Y0/giphy.gif" style="height:250px">
                </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/SVaJz9DQfv0xLXPSHm/giphy.gif" style="height:250px">
                </div>
            <div style="text-align:center">
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mytext">
                    <p>Step 1: Analyse Students’ Data</p>
                    <p>Select ‘Assessed Level’ to view data based on your students’ current level.</p>
                    <p>To see where your students sit in relation to their grade, select ‘Grade’.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mytext">
                    <p>Step 2: Select Individual Cells for Goal Sheets</p>
                    <p>Select the skills you want your students to develop by clicking on the individual cells.  Skills highlighted in light or dark orange indicate students are working below their assessed level for these skills.  These are ‘growth opportunities’, so you may want to generate goals sheets for these particular skills. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="mytext">
                    <p>Step 3: Generate all Goal Sheets</p>
                    <p>To generate all the student goal sheets as one PDF document, click on ‘Generate all Goal Sheets'. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="mytext">
          <p>Step 4: (Optional) Generate Individual Goal Sheets</p>
                <p>To generate individual student goal sheets, click on the download button next to the student’s name. This will enable you to print or email goal sheets for individual students. </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!